# HTML picture element for art directing and inline svg

Tags: image, svg, inline

I am using [polyfill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) for Art Directing two different different kinds of logos - one for desktop and the second one for mobile devices.

```
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 25em)"
srcset="logo_mobile.svg">
<source media="(max-width: 48em)"
srcset="logo.svg">
<img src="logo.svg">
</picture>
```

As I am doing various types of CSS3 Animations (drawing effect and moving gradient) to these Logos, I would like to use the SVG Code Inline.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: You could make it a data URL, that would be inline.

Comment: I think it's not possible to use Css3 Animations with Data URL

Comment: I think it is possible (modulo browser bugs of course).

Comment: Sorry for being stupid - but could you give me a code example? Thanks.

Comment: Sure https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-URL#HTML

Comment: This is fine when I wanted to use the image as a background via CSS - but I would like to use it the srcset attribute in the picture tag.

Comment: I don't understand what's stopping you from doing that? It's exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me - so I made a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scyh2o5v/

The Data URI works fine, but how can style it with CSS? 
style="fill:#ddd" doesn't work.

Comment: You'd need to embed the style in the data URI i.e. as part of the SVG file that you're encoding

Comment: as I wrote in the original thread: I would like to change the color (css3 gradient animation) on hover. Is this possible?

Comment: It isn't, whether you use a data URL or not. Images are not interactive.

Comment: I doing something similar to this:
http://codepen.io/ririne/pen/eNwjJm

But i don't hink its possible with Data URI - thanks anyway

Comment: It's not possible with a picture at all. Whether or not you use a data URL is irrelevant. Your question however merely states that you want the data inline which is what a data URL would give you.